# eloquent query make it faster

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

I have this function returning the percent of passed through points, it take long time to complete and I would like to know how to optimize it to make faster and/or on which fields add indexes.

```
public static function getTripCoverage($schedule_id,$cart_zone_id){
    
    $totboe = Points::where('cart_zone_id',$cart_zone_id)
      ->where('enabled', 1)
      ->where('tipo','controllo')
      ->count();

    $boepassate = Points::where('cart_zone_id',$cart_zone_id)
      ->where('enabled', 1)
      ->where('tipo','controllo')
      ->select('*',DB::raw('(select COUNT(*) as ch from events where boa_id = points.id and schedule_id = ' . $schedule_id . ') as passato'))
      ->havingRaw('passato > 0')
      ->get();

    $totpassate = count($boepassate);
    if($totboe>0 && $totpassate >0){
      $percboe = round($totpassate*100/$totboe);
    }else{
      $percboe = 0;
    }
    return $percboe;
}
```

Below the raw query output from eloquent

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select count(*) as aggregate from `points` where `cart_zone_id` = ? and `enabled` = ? and `tipo` = ? and `points`.`deleted_at` is null"
    "bindings" => array:3 [▼
      0 => 609
      1 => 1
      2 => "controllo"
    ]
    "time" => 0.33
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select *, (select COUNT(*) as ch from events where boa_id = points.id and schedule_id = 138) as passato from `points` where `cart_zone_id` = ? and `enabled` = ? ▶"
    "bindings" => array:3 [▼
      0 => 609
      1 => 1
      2 => "controllo"
    ]
    "time" => 0.22
  ]
]
```

Below the two table structure

```
    CREATE TABLE `events` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `code` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
 `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `device_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `schedule_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `boa_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `cartzone_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `pvd_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `parent_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `skip_unique` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`,`schedule_id`,`device_id`,`boa_id`,`cartzone_id`,`skip_unique`,`pvd_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=54306513 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    
    CREATE TABLE `points` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `schedule_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `customer_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `cart_zone_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `indirizzo` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `latitudine` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `longitudine` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `tipo` enum('smart','escluse','super smart','controllo') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `schedules_points_ibfk_1` (`schedule_id`),
 KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`),
 KEY `cart_zone_id` (`cart_zone_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `points_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`schedule_id`) REFERENCES `schedules` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `points_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `points_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`cart_zone_id`) REFERENCES `cart_zones` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5168 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

The table events contain 500k records, points around 5k records.

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score -1):

i have solved the problem adding on index the boa_id and schedule_id of the table events this drop the time from 1.7sec to 0.007 sec.

Comment: It is better to add an index to `enabled` and `tipo` columns too, also you should add an index to any foreign key columns if the foreign key constraint is not set.